# Updating df col values, using a condition on a col in another df, when a char col in both df can act as key

Tags: r, syntax, indexing, dataframe

I need to update values in a df column selectively, depending on the satisfaction of a condition on a column in df2, and providing as update values for df1, the values in a column of df2.  Both df have a col whose values are uniques, and the uniques in df2 are a proper subset of those in df1. The approach I have tried is to take the uniques column values in both df, and turn them into row names, use them to define a selection index, which is created out of df2, and then applied to df1 for a value update.  I got the syntax to work (eventually!) by using  numerical subscripting to define columns, in combination with my character-based shared key index for rows.    Whew.

But is there a simpler, more efficient, and more "R" way of doing this than the one I am attempting, using a built-in, perhaps?  I will need to scale. Test example follows:

```
goo <- data.frame(Uids=c("UidD", "UidA", "UidC"), Payout=c(3,0,5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
moo <- data.frame(Uids=c("UidB", "UidC", "UidA", "UidD"), PayOut=0, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
goo
  Uids Payout
1 UidD      3
2 UidA      0
3 UidC      5
moo
  Uids PayOut
1 UidB      0
2 UidC      0
3 UidA      0
4 UidD      0
# I want to update moo$Payout with the value of goo$Payout, for matching Uids,
# when goo$Payout > 0, i.e. moo[4,2] <- goo[1,2]; moo[2,2 <- goo[3,2]
rownames(goo) <- goo$Uids
rownames(moo) <- moo$Uids
#I am trying to create and apply an index based on turning uids into rownames
IndexToUpdate <- goo$Uids[goo$Payout>0]
IndexToUpdate
[1] "UidD" "UidC"
 moo[IndexToUpdate, 2] <- goo[IndexToUpdate, 2]
#this works, but is there a better way to do it?
moo
     Uids PayOut
UidB UidB      0
UidC UidC      5
UidA UidA      0
UidD UidD      3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `merge` with `all.x = TRUE`:

```
voo <- merge(moo, goo, by = "Uids", all.x = TRUE)
voo
#   Uids PayOut.x PayOut.y
# 1 UidA        0        0
# 2 UidB        0       NA
# 3 UidC        0        5
# 4 UidD        0        3
```

Then `ifelse`:

```
within(voo, PayOut <- ifelse(is.na(PayOut.y), PayOut.x, PayOut.y))
#   Uids PayOut.x PayOut.y PayOut
# 1 UidA        0        0      0
# 2 UidB        0       NA      0
# 3 UidC        0        5      5
# 4 UidD        0        3      3
```

---

The same thing using `data.table`s:

```
library(data.table)
GOO <- data.table(goo)
MOO <- data.table(moo)
setkey(GOO, Uids)
setkey(MOO, Uids)
VOO <- GOO[MOO]
VOO[, FinalPayout := ifelse(is.na(PayOut), PayOut.1, PayOut)]
```

Comment: Thanks, flodel.  Hadn't picked up on all.x flag to merge, and this makes it possible.  (Alongside the tidy-up operation you provide.)  Arun and flodel, haven't started to use data.table yet - I'm still trying to get my head around the basics - but it crops up so often in SO recommendations that it might queue-jump.